# MySQL get content from web page (or other network resource)

Tags: mysql, curl

Is it possible to open a curl like object in MySQL?

What I would like to do is create procedure which would check to see if a certain value is returned from a specific URL like http://example.com/inschedule?id=200&time=20m. The returned result would be a simple string like 1 or 0.

I know it is better to have a script do this by putting a entry into a table etc. However, it would be much less complex for me to be able to do it this way.

Thanks

Comment: That's like making Gods of War 2 in assembler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [Curl (UDF) Functions for MySQL](https://launchpad.net/curludfs) so I guess it is possible. I have not tired it yet so I can't say how well it works.

Comment: The source code is here http://patg.net/downloads/curl_functions_mysql-0.1.tar.gz

Answer (score -2):

Don't ask your refrigerator to make a coffee.
Mysql is a database demon. Some database servers even can dance a polka for you, yes. But mysql will not. It merely serve SQL requests. And you're terrible wrong about complexities. You'll have a lot of them, trying to implement it this way